# QAbstractItemModel for QTreeView: what an I doing wrong?

Tags: qt, model, pyqt, qabstractitemmodel

I want to create a subclass a `QAbstractItemModel` to use it in `QTreeView`. At first, I decided to make a minimalistic model without any hierarchy supported. It should give a 2-by-3 table with simple text data (read-only one).

Alas, It does not crash but does not show any data: only a few column headers (1, 2). Cannot someone tell me, what am I doing wrong?

```
import os, sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg

from PyQt5.QtCore import QPointF, QRectF
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsItem


from gui.graphic_items import *



class MegaModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._root_item = 7.40
        pass

    def columnCount(self, parent_index):
        if parent_index.isValid():
            return 0
        else:
            return 2

    def rowCount(self, parent_index):
        if parent_index.isValid():
            return 0
        else:
            return 3

    def data(self, index, role):
        if index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant("Oy vey!")
        else:
            return None

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        print("index", row, column, parent)

        if parent.isValid():
            print("valid")
            return parent.internalPointer()
        else:
            print("invalid")
            return self.createIndex(row, column, self._root_item)

    def parent(self, index):
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)


    mega_view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()

    mega_model = MegaModel()

    mega_view.setModel(mega_model)

    mega_view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why are you returning `parent.internalPointer()` from `index` method if `parent` index is valid?

Comment: Well, I've just tried to modify this to return`QtCore.QModelndex()` when `parent` is valid. Nothing chaged, the desired cells does not appear...

Comment: There's the second mistake as well, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes:

1. You shouldn't return `parent.internalPointer()` from `index` method - this method does not return the model's stored values, it is meant to only return indexes to model items
2. In `data` method you return `QtCore.QVariant("Oy vey!")` for all roles. You should really only return this for `QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole`, for other roles it is ok to return `None`:

   ```
   def data(self, index, role):
       if not index.isValid():
           return None
       if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
           return index.internalPointer()
       else:
           return None
   ```

Comment: Also, cannot you have a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42565139/qabstractitemmodel-annoying-branch-line-in-qtreeview

Comment: UPD: already fixed, the tree.siblings() gave only the siblings of a node (the node itself was not listed).